# showing Invalid Phone Number for different country except india

Tags: android

I have activity in which two field is there one for email and second for Phone number with country spinner 
when i enter contact number and select India country flag it shows valid if i change the country flag it shows invalid.

Here is the output `https://drive.google.com/open?id=1fTA3_vu5lLqh19RGfnGy6V4P3v95B2mc`

```
https://drive.google.com/open?id=19C14XBbYUfPyEul8MVn_96mdN5quaOx2
```

Here is the code

```
 private void validateFields() {
        if (!CommonUtils.isValidEmail(email.getText().toString())) {
            email.setHintMessage(getString(R.string.invalidemail));
            email.setRequestFocus();
            email.setUpperHintColor(Color.parseColor("#EE3437"));
            email.setHintTextColor(Color.parseColor("#EE3437"));

            // mEmail.setInputTextLayoutColor(Color.parseColor("#8e57fb"));
            //  mEmail.sethintEditMessage("Enter Email");
            return;
        }


        PhoneNumberUtil phoneUtil = PhoneNumberUtil.getInstance();
        try {
            Phonenumber.PhoneNumber swissNumberProto = phoneUtil.parse(countrySpinner.getText().toString() + phonenumber.getText().toString(), countryName);
            boolean isvalidph = phoneUtil.isValidNumberForRegion(swissNumberProto, countryName);
                    /*isValidNumberForRegion(swissNumberProto, countryName);*/
            if (!isvalidph) {
                //mPhone.setError(getString(R.string.error_field_required));
                // mPhonenumber.requestFocus();
                // focusView = mPhonenumber;
                //  CommonDialogUtility.getInstance().createDialog(PhoneNumberVerificationActivity.this, "Invalid mobile number");
                phonenumber.setHintMessage(getString(R.string.invalidphonenumber));
                phonenumber.setRequestFocus();
                phonenumber.setUpperHintColor(Color.parseColor("#EE3437"));
                phonenumber.setHintTextColor(Color.parseColor("#EE3437"));
                 Log.d("validation of phone","validation of phone");
                return;
                //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Invalid mobile number", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        } catch (NumberParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            phonenumber.setHintMessage(getString(R.string.invalidphonenumber));
            phonenumber.setRequestFocus();
            phonenumber.setUpperHintColor(Color.parseColor("#EE3437"));
            phonenumber.setHintTextColor(Color.parseColor("#EE3437"));
            //CommonDialogUtility.getInstance().createDialog(PhoneNumberVerificationActivity.this, "Invalid mobile number");
            return;

        }

        makeUserExistsAPICall();
        //   makeSendOTPCall();

    }
```

Comment: What is the value of `countryName`

Comment: `isvalidph` will be false if `countryName` and country code does not match. Please make sure they are the same.

Comment: isValidNumberForRegion() validate the number with respect to Region?

Comment: [See this](https://github.com/googlei18n/libphonenumber/blob/master/FAQ.md#when-should-i-use-isvalidnumberforregion)

Answer (score 0):

`isValidNumberForRegion()` validate the number with respect to Region. You can use the following functions to check for a valid number

> isPossibleNumber - quickly guessing whether a number is a possible phonenumber by using only the length information, much faster than a full validation.
>
> isValidNumber - full validation of a phone number for a region using length and prefix information.